# R - Print Contents of Rows with 2 duplicated column values

Tags: r, duplicates

I am trying to do the following in R:
**What I have:** .csv datafile with 38 columns and ~49,000 rows
**What I want:** To create a datafile that only lists rows that have duplicates.  I don't want to look for duplicates in EVERY column, just TWO columns in particular.

Example:

Column   |    1   |       **2**    |       3     |       **4**

Sample A  |   jkl  |     **SAME**    |    sfio     |   **SAME2**

Sample B  |   sfa    |   **SAME**   |     sdi     |    **SAME2**

Sample C  |   sfjk   |   **SAME**    |    idso    |    **lskf**

Sample D  |   idf    |   **SAME3**   |    sfdjkl   |   **SAME4**

Sample E  |   dfk    |   **SAME3**     |   iodfs   |   **SAME4**

I want the output of ALL columns (Column-4) of any row where Columns 2 & 4 (bolded columns) are the same...in this case, I want Samples A, B, D, & E.

Here is my code so far, trying to find duplicates in Columns Gene and AAChange:

```
findduplicates <- function(file){
        data <- read.csv(file)
        d <- which(duplicated(data[,Gene]) & duplicated(data[,AAChange]))
        rowdups <- table(d)
        rowdups
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:
 Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , Gene) : undefined columns selected

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: your example data does not have "Gene" or "AAChange" as column names, and if it did, you would need to put the column name in quotes.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, my column names are what I listed.  I've added quotations (ugh...simple issues) which solves the ERROR, and now, the output is pretty much EVERY row, and the output has the row number and then 1.
(e.g. 3000 1  3001 1 3002 1 etc.)  There should only be a few hundred duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, here is one way:

```
df <- read.table(text="jkl | SAME | sfio | SAME2
sfa | SAME | sdi | SAME2
sfjk | SAME | idso | lskf
idf | SAME3 | sfdjkl | SAME4
dfk | SAME3 | iodfs | SAME4",
sep='|')

interact <- interaction(df[[2]], df[[4]])
df[duplicated(interact) | duplicated(interact, fromLast=TRUE), ]
#     V1      V2       V3     V4
# 1 jkl    SAME     sfio   SAME2
# 2 sfa    SAME      sdi   SAME2
# 4 idf   SAME3   sfdjkl   SAME4
# 5 dfk   SAME3    iodfs   SAME4
```

Comment: Applying this to my function worked.  The documentation on interaction is kind of confusing, but I'm looking into it.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

```
df[duplicated(df$x) & duplicated(df$z),]
```

No need for the `which` declaration, subsetting does that automatically.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "c"), y = c(1:4), z = c("d", "d", "e", "f"), stringsAsFactors=F)
  x y z
1 a 1 d
2 a 2 d
3 b 3 e
4 c 4 f
df[duplicated(df$x) & duplicated(df$z),]
  x y z
2 a 2 d
```

## Old

```
df[df$x==df$z,]
```

Here's the data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c(1:3), z = c("a", "d", "c"), stringsAsFactors=F)
df
  x y z
1 a 1 a
2 b 2 d
3 c 3 c

df[df$x==df$z,]
  x y z
1 a 1 a
3 c 3 c
```

R is going line by line in column x and matching it to the same row in column z.

Comment: Oh!  That makes sense!  I've edited my code: d<-data[data$Gene == data$AAChange,].  Now it just lists the column headers + <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names).  I know there are duplicates.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the edit. I was matching exact rows. You just want repeats, not necessarily the same repeats.

Comment: It still isn't providing the correct output. It is capturing the last of the duplicated rows. There should be a change in the code completely. I will put another edit.

Comment: Thanks, again.  Issue is solved below, but I definitely was able to use this for another part of my code (where I JUST spit out the last of the duplicated rows).  Thank you.